# Clarification about LoadVector syntax (transforming a txt file into a vector)

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working on a project and am having trouble with Loadvector syntax. So far I have this

```
/* ----------------------------------------- */
/* --------------LoadVector ---------------- */
/* ----------------------------------------- */
vector <int> LoadVector(string filename) {
    vector <int> c;

    cout << "Open the file" << endl;
    ifstream cf(filename);

    // test file open
    if (cf.is_open()) {
        int value;

        // read the elements in the file into a vector
        while (cf >> value) c.push_back(value);

        // close the file
        cout << "Close the file" << endl;
        cf.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "File not found" <<endl;
    }
    return c;
}
```

when I try to build it I get 
'Open the File 
File Not Found'

The files are a series of numbers and I have them saved within the project folder as .txt documents. I think that I'm missing something in where the program is pointing to get the files. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Check that you don't have the input file already open in another application, such as notepad (on windows). if it is, your program will not be able to open the file.

Comment: Tried this and still no luck. I got an error with an "Expression: vector subscript out of range". The files I'm trying to open have 7 numbers total so I know they are not too large, guessing vector subscript is referring to something else?

Comment: Please show how you invoke `LoadVector`

Comment: ```
        vector <int>c1 = LoadVector("class1.txt");
        vector <int>c2 = LoadVector("class2.txt");
        vector <int>c3 = LoadVector("class3.txt");
        vector <int>c4 = LoadVector("class4.txt");
        vector <int>c5 = LoadVector("class5.txt");
      
```

This is in the int main. My apologies on the formatting. The goal is to read the numbers in each file and convert to a vector. The files are saved in the source folder and appear in the UI as "other files".

Comment: Try: 1) replacing the string 'class1.txt' with the full path to the file, e.g. c:\\users\\matt\\class1.txt', or 2) copy the file 'class1.txt' into the same folder that the executable binary. Then re-run your app. This should address the 'File Not Found' issue you are seeing.

Comment: @PhillipNgan That worked!!! Thank you so much!